# How to show the file name using javascript in web page?

Tags: javascript

I want to show the name of the file that was open using java script is it possible 
e.g. my filename is abcd.html i want when this webpage is open the name abcd is writeen in heading

please help me

Comment: You mean something like `alert(window.location);`?

Comment: Welcome, @Shivam. You will have a better success getting a good answer if you improve your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) element

```
<head>
 <title>abcd</title>
</head>
```